# Suggestion for building an add-on to create a report about email attachments

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I want to write an add-on for gmail, just for hobby but the intention is to learn about it. I have never written any such add-on before, however I am a software developer.

I am requesting here your suggestion. My Gmail add-on will be iterating over all emails that contain PDF attachment in the users email. It then will read out the PDFs that it finds and try to create a report accordingly. The report will be based on some keywords in the PDF. So, where do you suggest me to start with? Is this possible at all in an add-on since I need to open PDF and read it out?

Thank you very much

Comment: We have this class [`GmailAttachment`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment) that you can check to help you start with. Also, try to visit the [`Users.messages.attachments`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments) for further information about gmail attachments.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 thank you very much for your input. Any idea about the PDF part? I don't want to start the project and fail because I can't do any PDF operation in such an app. Do you know that?